# How to store custom (non-task) data in MS-Project file?

Tags: c#, vsto, project-management, ms-project

I'm writing a Project add-on (VSTO) using C#, to programatically generate an Earned Value Chart (Planned effort vs. Actual effort vs. Actual work completed), and I want to store ***weekly actual effort*** data within the Microsoft Project 2016 (MSP) file (.mpp).

In MSP: we don't need to know how much effort was spent on *each activity*. For this chart, I only require the *actual effort for entire project for each week*. We use different systems for measuring *planned effort* versus *actual effort* for each dev activity.

Sample dataset that I want to store:

`Week#       Hrs per week
2018-W16     900.00
2018-W17    1038.50
2018-W18     811.25`

I've got solutions for deriving/storing "*Planned effort*" and "*Actual work completed*".  The final piece would be solved if I could store this "*Weekly actual effort*" data in the MSP file.

AFAIK, and to avoid  [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): the contraints listed below are preventing me from using built-in MSP features (to generate graph) or datastore (to store my custom data).

### Constraints

- Within each project plan, I cannot alter these values on *existing* tasks: `Resource Names`, `Duration`, `Start`, `Finish`, `Predecessor`, `Successor`. Doing so would alter the plan and incur wrath of Architect and Project Manager upon me.
- Our teams' actual hours are tracked in multiple external systems (eg: VSTS, Basecamp, custom app), and isn't subject to change to support my needs.

  - Extracting this data from MSP and time-tracking systems, then manually creating dataset to generate Earned Value Chart (in Excel) takes too long, want to automate this.
  - Assigning time-phased actual hours onto tasks (via `View > Task Usage`) has consequence of  MSP automatically adjusting `Duration` on that task, which violates constraint above.
  - Tasks in MSP and items in external time-tracking systems are not mapped one-to-one. Manually deciding which hours go onto which MSP tasks is onerous and time-consuming. Storing hours with dates on MSP tasks suffers consequences mentioned in previous issue (auto-adjustment of `Duration`).
- Arch & PM require project setting `Auto-scheduling` to be enabled. Manually-scheduled tasks are allowed, provided they are individually manually set this way (eg: manually override `Start`). I can temporarily disable `Auto-scheduling` during operations (via `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application.Calculation = PjCalculation.pjManual`), as long as I restore it afterwards.

### What I've tried

- Create dummy task with `Duration = 0 days`, and record hours via `View > Task Usage`. When assigning any hours to this task, MSP automatically adjusts `Duration` accordingly.  Since this task now appears within the project plan, I suspect Arch/PM won't approve, since they make calculations from `Duration` values in the project.
- Create a dummy user that isn't assigned to any tasks, and attempt to assign hours to it via `View > Resource Usage`.  MSP prevents this (greyed-out), until I assign user to a task.  Assigning this dummy user to any task, and then assigning any hours data, will result in MSP auto-adjusting `Duration`.
- Create a dummy milestone task. Set fields: `Duration = 0`, `Start = last day of week`, `Finish = last day of week`, and store the weekly actual hours in a custom field (to avoid MSP auto-adjustment of `Duration`). Repeat for each week of project execution.

  - Technically this works, but requires user applying a filter (via `View > Data > Filter`) to avoid seeing all these extra dummy tasks (one per week) appearing within the project. I'm hoping for a better solution to store this data, or a better way to hide this data from user.
- Examine .mpp file.  Stored as binary data, which I can't decode. Attempt to learn datastore possibilities via [Project Data Interchange XML Element Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968664(v=office.12).aspx) docs and MSP export to XML: I'm not seeing any fields I can use that wouldn't violate constraints listed above.
- Google-fu: my searches for `custom data storage ms project` returns info about using custom-fields, which isn't enough to solve.

Comment: I've just spent the last year baking an EVMS into project using Excel to store the non-project data. If you want to get in touch I can give you the tour.

Comment: @EricChristoph: sure!  How to get in touch, without broadcasting our emails to spammers?

Comment: Look me up on LinkedIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your core problem is: I want to store project-level (so not task/resource/assignment data) somewhere in the .mpp flie. Take a look at a similar discussion [Where can I save the settings entered by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934885/where-can-i-save-the-settings-entered-by-the-user/48951666#48951666) ; there's expanded information about custom fields which I think may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, your solution `ActiveProject.Comments = "really long strings"` works well for this purpose. During debugging, I noticed another MSP add-on storing some JSON data in there, confirming your approach. Nice!